# How to read first 2 number of every line in listbox vb . Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have  listbox has lines like this

12345678%32=5

4663578877fg

6883346899

,,,etc

How can I get the first two number of every line to be like this

12

46

68

BTW the listbox has only numbers in first of every line

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need help with how to get all the listboxes or how to get the two first characters?

Comment: Not this and this,  I want to get the first 2 number of every line....  in other way I want delete every thing in all lines expect the first two number in every line..  sorry for bad english

Answer (score 2):

```
myListBox.Items.Add("1234")
myListBox.Items.Add("567")
myListBox.Items.Add("890")
For position As Integer = 0 To myListBox.Items.Count - 1
    myListBox.Items(position) = CStr(myListBox.Items(position)).Substring(0, 2)
Next
```

**EDIT**

We can use the RichTextBox.Lines property that returns a array of String. Each String in the array represents a line in the RichTextBox. If you want to store the first two digits in an array, you can try :

```
Dim intValues(Convert.ToInt32(RichTextBox1.Lines.Length)) As Integer 'Stores the digits
For position As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(RichTextBox1.Lines.Length) - 1
        intValues(position) = Convert.ToInt32(RichTextBox1.Lines(position).Substring(0, 2))
Next
```

Comment: Bro you didn't get it...  I want to get the first  2number of each line in the listbox  or richtextbox. And there are many lines in the text file

Comment: @ryan2014 you didnt say anything about a richtextbox OR a textfile. What he provided is what you requested. Popping off like that wont get you anywhere here. If its not what you wanted I would recommend changing your question with better details. Also as per your comment above  "I want delete every thing in all lines expect the first two number in every line.." his proposed answer does this.

Comment: I didn't. Mean that,  I tried to explain more, sorry this is my fault. Because I'm using phone , I will edit the question with more details

Comment: @ryan2014 Check the Edit for getting values from the RichTextbox